# Does the ubuntu 22.04 use the fast installation algorithm, like 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, 22.04

Compared to Ubuntu 18.04, it takes less time to install Ubuntu 20.04 due to new compression algorithms.

I wander weather 22.04 still use the same algorithm.
I couldn't find any post explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the following line from the 20.04 (Focal) [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes).  It indicates lz4 compression is used for the kernel and the initramfs.

> Boot speed improvements through changing the default kernel compression algorithm to lz4 (in Ubuntu 19.10) on most architectures, and changing the default initramfs compression algorithm to lz4 on all architectures.

I believe with 22.04 the default kernel compression and initramfs compression were changed to zstd.  I have not found anything as obvious as a line in the Jammy Release Notes, but these commands on a stock 22.04 server indicate zstd.

```
root@ubuntu:~# grep CONFIG_KERNEL_ /boot/config-$(uname -r)
# CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZO is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4 is not set
CONFIG_KERNEL_ZSTD=y
```

```
root@ubuntu:~# grep COMPRESS /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz | zstd ]
COMPRESS=zstd
```

There is also a [bug report (LP: #1931725)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1931725) where the change and speed impacts were discussed.

These compression options affect boot time and will have very little effect on installation time.

**other links**

- [How do I demonstrate the type of kernel compression in practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553185/how-do-i-demonstrate-the-type-of-kernel-compression-in-practice)
- [Revisiting default initramfs compression](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041726.html)
- [current ubuntu kernel compression method is breaking VMs using pygrub (Xen)](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2022-January/019165.html)
- https://docs.kernel.org/x86/boot.html